# How to give notification in Server when a Client is connected and how to broadcast message to the other clients (Java Socket Connection UDP)?

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I took code from some sources in internet, here it is:

Server Side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Server {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
        serverSocket.setBroadcast(true);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

        while (true) {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                    receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            //System.out.println(serverSocket.getAddress().getHostAddress());
                System.out.println(receivePacket.getAddress().getHostAddress()+" is connected");
            String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence +" from: "+receivePacket.getAddress().getHostAddress());

            InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();
            System.out.println("Port: "+port);
            String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
            sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();


            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,sendData.length, IPAddress, port); //
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
        }
    }
}
```

Client1 Side:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class Client1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        clientSocket.setBroadcast(true);
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
        Boolean status = true;

        while(status){
        String sentence = "";
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
        if(sentence.equals("exit")){
            break;
        }
        sendData = sentence.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,receiveData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
        String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
        System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
        }

        clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Client2 Side: same as Client1.

My questions are:

- how to give notification in Server side which will tell you the client's IP address when a client is connected?
- how to broadcast message from one client to the other clients? ex: Client1 sends message to Server, the Server broadcast the message to all of its clients, not only to Client1.

Thank you in advance